# Convert negative .days to 0?

Tags: c#, datetime, negative-number

I am trying to compare the "end date" of a "contract" against datetime.now. Obviously, if todays date surpasses the contract end date then the value is returned as negative. I want a value that is negative to return as 0 while any end date that has happened yet will return as a positive value.

Currently, the positive value works properly however negative values get returned as:

-41641

The code used to calculate the value is as follows:

```
var contractEndDate = contract.EndDate;
var ts = contractEndDate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
var contractDaysRemaining = ts.Days;
```

contractDaysRemaining then returns the value later in the code.

I'm pretty new to c# and would like to know how to go about converting a negative contractDaysRemaining to 0 while leaving a positive value untouched.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

To do this, you want to use [`Math.Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx).

```
var contractDaysRemaining = Math.Max(ts.Days, 0);
```

`Max()` returns the higher of two values, so if you give it `0` as one of them it will only affect negative numbers.

I highly suggest looking at the other methods in the [Math class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math_methods.aspx) as well, since there's a lot of useful ones in there.  `Round()`, for instance.

Comment: this worked. thank you very much for the info. I'll be sure to check into the math class further as well, thank you!

Comment: @Gerald - I'm glad it helped, and good luck with your C# experiences!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
var contractDaysRemaining = ts.Days < 0 ? 0 : ts.Days;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var contractDaysRemaining = Math.Max(ts.Days, 0);
```

It takes the maximum of the value or zero.  You could also do:

```
var contractDaysRemaining = ts.Days < 0 ? 0 : ts.Days;
```

Not quite as clear.

Comment: the math.max method was what I chose to use. it worked well, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var contractDaysRemaining = ts.Days > 0 ? ts.Days : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(contractDaysRemaining < 0)
    contractDaysRemaining = 0
```

just add that line at the end there